# Mod_rewrite conflict?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my mod_rewrite rules that I cannot manage to figure out myself!

Essentially I have a directory of countries (100+) that will display (#worldwide) the country information depending on the URL.

I also have a fishing clubs directory that I have instructed .htaccess to ignore this rule. This seems to be working ok for the base directory, however I cannot get it to redirect /fishing-clubs/name-of-country  to /fishing-clubs/index.php?country=COUNTRY

website.com//fishing-clubs/ is going to the /fishing-clubs/ directory.

However website.com/fishing-clubs/name-of-country/ is giving a 404 error.

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

```
    RewriteRule ^fishing-clubs/ - [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^fishing-clubs/([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/?$ /fishing-clubs/index.php?country=$1 [NC]


    #worldwide
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1&admin1code=$2 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-s_()]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1&admin1code=$2&admin2code=$3 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s_()]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-s_()]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-s_()]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1&admin1code=$2&admin2code=$3&city=$4 [NC]
```

Comment: Sorry I edited a bit to explain more. website/fishing-clubs/ Works fine. website/fishing-clubs/name-of-country/ gives a 404 Error

Comment: Because without it, it will think that /fishing-clubs/ is a country because of the #worldwide rules. I need to exclude this so that it opens the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^fishing-clubs/?$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^fishing-clubs/([\w()-]+)/?$ /fishing-clubs/index.php?country=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#worldwide
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1&admin1code=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1&admin1code=$2&admin2code=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/?$ country-admin-city.php?country=$1&admin1code=$2&admin2code=$3&city=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: You sir are a genius :) Thank you so much!